# Impersonate a user via Salesforce REST API?

Tags: api, rest, salesforce, impersonation

Is there a way to impersonate a user via the Salesforce REST API so you only get the see the data that he has access to? E.g. You would only retrieve the contacts the impersonated user is allowed to see.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce's authorization system automatically enforces visibility to data based on the authenticated user's security profile. So, make sure you authenticate as the user you want to impersonate. There's nothing else you have to do.

Comment: What if you do not have the credentials of that user but only those of an administrator?

Comment: There's no way to do this reliably. If you wanted to do something like only show records owned by a certain user, you'd probably be ok. But salesforce's security model has a lot of complexities, and when you think of profile settings, record ownership, access via sharing rules, access via reporting structure, and so on, it is virtually impossible to replicate this yourself.